# there is any answer for image upload error in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i upload the i got this error in rails application

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature):
```

i used form for upload image like this one

```
<%= form.label :image, "Profile Photo" %>
  <%= form.file_field :image %>
```

this is my model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one_attached :image
  
end
```

this is my controller params:

```
def user_params
    params.permit(:name, :phone, :address, :gender, :adhar_number, :image)
  end
```

Comment: please show the form element for your form

Answer (score 0):

Your form should look like this:

```
<%= form.label :image, "Profile Photo" %>
  <%= form.file_field :image, accept: "image/*", direct_upload: true %>
```

It works fine for me. Try this one if you have an error like this.